# Python - Pandas module column rename not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I am starting to learn and understand panda module in Python. However, my issue is with the rename string. The rename works fine when i use print, this shows the column has been renamed:

```
print(data.rename(columns={"Rep": "Name"}))
```

However, when i use print(data), to show all of the data from the document, the column does not show as being renamed. This also does not show when the file has been exported using the data.to_csv("example.csv") string.

Would really appreciate if somebody could shed some light on this please.

Full Source code below:

```
import pandas as pd
    
data = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Downloads\Book1.xlsx")

del data["Region"]
del data["Item"]

print(data.rename(columns={"Rep": "Name"})

print(data)

data.to_csv("example.csv")
```

Comment: You need to assign the changes back to something, else you discard them: `data=data.rename(columns={"Rep": "Name"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inplace argument, to make the changes reflect in the DataFrame as well, like this:

```
data.rename(columns={"Rep": "Name"}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Just tested this and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for this! Can i just ask, would i need to use inplace for other changes to the DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, so if you refer to the documentation for rename, you'll find that rename returns a DataFrame if inplace is set to False, in that case you could have kept inplace as False and stored your DataFrame likewise: data=data.rename(columns={"Rep": "Name"}) , but if you set inplace as True, the return type is None and it would just store the changes in the DataFrame. I'm not sure if you had this question only for rename or for other methods as well, but all methods with the inplace parameter have this similar behaviour, you use the inplace parameter to save the changes in the main DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'inplace=True' to data.rename

```
print(data.rename(columns={"Rep": "Name"}, inplace=True))
```

Comment: Hi - you and another comment had the same solution, and both work how i was expecting. Thanks for your input - really appreciate it